# Angular Module style not applied

Tags: javascript, angular, sass

**users.component.scss**

```
h1 { 
    align-items: center;
    color: #212736;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Manrope;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
p {
    color: #212736;
    font-family: Manrope;
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    line-height: 18px;
    margin-top: 26px;
    opacity: .6;
}
```

**users.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users.component.scss']
})
```

**users.component.html**

```
<h1>Users List</h1>
<p>Show all users info</p>
```

Currently Scss style not working in our users module. how to solve it.

I am find best solution for this.

Anyone help me.

Comment: Did you try with `:host { h1: {styles}  p: {styles} }` ?

Comment: This should not be needed. Can you try to reproduce this issue in a blank StackBlitz project?

Comment: Code as posted should work. e.g. [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hikw8k?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts). Double check scss not css, inspect in browser to see what styles are being applied and whether applied or overridden.